# Correct the sentences

Tags: grammaticality

1. I like traveling around the world.
2. I like going traveling around the world.
3. I like going to travel around the world.
4. I like going for traveling around the world.

Comment: Welcome to ELL stack exchange.  Please read the contributors’ guide.  This question— “correct these sentences for me” — is an example of what not to do.   Please clean up the question and keep contributing!

Answer (score 1):

Below I list your example sentences and suggestions for them:

```
#1   I like traveling around the world.
```

This sentence has correct usage and grammar. Its meaning is that you like travel, especially long distance (world) traveling.

```
#2   I like going traveling around the world.
```

This sentence has acceptable grammar but is clumsier than the first sentence. It would be less clumsy as "I like to go traveling around the world." The use of the word 'go' or 'going' implies you enjoy the start of a world trip, but doesn't strongly imply any feelings of liking for the entire traveling process. You enjoy leaving on a long trip, but you may or may not enjoy returning home.

```
#3   I like going to travel around the world.
```

I would change this sentence to "I like to travel around the world." which has the same meaning as your first example sentence.

```
#4   I like going for traveling around the world.
```

This example sentence is not grammatical without major changes. I recommend using my replacement sentence #2 instead.